# Make Vue data globally available and accessible for all components

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vue-component

In have a simple Vue cli app with some pages.

In **Users.vue** I fetch the data from an API with axios:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.github.com/users')
      .then(response => (this.users = response.data))
  }
}
</script>
```

This works fine. I can access the properties.

But how do I add *axios* and the mounted hook globally e.g. to **App.vue** and be able to access the data from the json in every component?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the data from everywhere in your application. you should save it in store. using `vuex`. https://vuex.vuejs.org/

another way could be fine too, in case you need the data just in user's children. you can simply pass the data by using `props` https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: now in `App.js` I placed the mounted hook and from within my router link `<router-link to="/users" :users="users">Users</router-link>` I try to pass the prop. But the data is not available in the child component? There I accept the prop `props: ['users'],`

Comment: You can pass your props data this way:  `<router-link :to="{ path: '/users', query: { myprop: 'someValue' }}">`, but for list of users, I think it's not ideal way. store it in vuex is much better solution in your situation.